# Java Swing: Ctrl+F1 does not work globally, but each other key combination

Tags: java, swing, keyevent

I have a swing gui with a tabbed pane in the north. Several key events are added to its input map:

```
InputMap paneInputMap = pane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
paneInputMap.put( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( KeyEvent.VK_E, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK ), "finish");
paneInputMap.put( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( KeyEvent.VK_F1, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK ), "toggletoolbar");
```

If the tabbed pane or another button in a toolbar has the focus, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> has no function. If another component is focused (e.g. JTree), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> executes the action.

The problem is, that it workes everywhere if I change the Keycode to e.g. `VK_F2`.

The key <kbd>F1</kbd> is'nt used anywhere else in the program.

Any idea?

Thanks,
André

**Edit:** A full text search in the java source code gave the answer: The `ToolTipManager` registeres the Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to display the tooltip text if the key combination is pressed. So if a button with a tooltip is focused, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is handled by the `ToolTipManager`. Otherwise my action is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that this gets an answer, here's the solution copied from your edit in the question. ;-)

> The ToolTipManager registeres the Key
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to display the tooltip text if
>   the key combination is pressed. So if
>   a button with a tooltip is focused,
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is handled by the
>   ToolTipManager. Otherwise my action is
>   called.

Answer (score 0):

May be the OS retargets the <kbd>F1</kbd> key? Install a key listener and see what events are handled.

BTW: It would help if you could edit your question and insert some testable code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After a long time of searching the java-code, if found the answer (see edit). The used OS only handles key events with ALT pressed ;)